# How to enter separate amounts then give feedback if the total meets a given amount?

Tags: design-patterns, feedback, error-message, input-fields

**case:**
During an ordering process, the user should be able to divide a given amount of money into a '1 to infinite' number of pots. So the sum of everything should be exactly the same when the step is finished. There is no 'others' option.

**solution?**
I was thinking of a single line with a input field for label and input field for amount with the possibility to add each time an extra 'line' with a new input field. That field is pre filled with the amount that is not divided yet.

**question**
Is this the best option to go with, or is there a more intuitive solution?

Comment: Does this question answer your query, or is your issue not covered by this post? http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17789/app-interface-for-changing-relational-percentages

Comment: @JonW Thanks for the suggestion. It almost covered my question. The challenge is the number of parts can be over 10 and input should also be able 'by keyboard'.

Comment: @Rene: Did you read all of the answers there? I think they cover your situation, too.

Comment: None of the answers deals with a text-only interface. They all are graphical interfaces (primarily mouse based, or with illustrations to exemplify the relative amounts). I do not think this question significantly overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds completely workable. I would suggest a few enhancements to ensure it is user friendly:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f521iL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

- Display the remainder every time they update, so that they know how much is unallocated.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Q8PE.png)</sup>

- The remainder will go negative when too much is allocated, or alternatively you could prevent overallocation (the above mockup might be what a user sees after attempting to type **20** in the amount, rather than 12.85).
- Also seen above, you need to provide a way to remove entries (red X on the left).
- Clicking an existing entry should immediately allow editing of the name and/or amount. Hovering over an item should highlight it to encourage clicking; perhaps even changing it to a TextBox on hover, to clarify to the user that they can edit existing items. As a somewhat less pretty interface (but just as usable) the existing items could simply remain textboxes as they are added.

Comment: Thank you for this clear example. Eventually I made the design with "immediate" input fields (to be consistent with the existing GUI of the app).